# What is the best solution to show NEWS html body using Objective-C?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsattributedstring

I'm building **news** app. I need to beautifully show the **body** of news in separate page. The body may contain `bold, italic, images, links, paragraphs` etc, the all kind of **html tags** occurred in article body.

Years before I would use [RTLabel](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel) but it's not supported anymore. I wouldn't mess with old libraries.

I thought about **UIWebView**, but I need something more native and easy to customize. What you think?

 What about [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel), is it the right choice I should consider?

Comment: Why dont u use `WKWebview`, it is available after iOS8+ and its a very good replacement for `UIWebview`.

Comment: you can use NSAttributed string and display it in UILabel.

Comment: @SahebRoy Wow! That guy really exists? =) I just found out about it!

Comment: @AlmasAdilbek didnt get if that was a sarcasm or a genuine reply.

Comment: @SahebRoy Thank you, i tried WKWebView. What if I want to put wkwebview between custom UIViews, where wkwebview must size to fit it's content in order to make it as a part of whole page?

Comment: You can do that as well, as you have to create `WKWebview` and give it a frame. You can control its position and dimensions. But you cannot put a view in between the `WKWebview's` content. IF you do that view would float over the webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WKWebview` for your purpose and it would serve you well.
As far as the customizing the `WKWebview` in between view and stretching it for its full content, YES you can do that as well,as long as the `WKWebview` content is a whole and you dont want a view in between the webview content.

Here's what you got to do --

1. Put a scrollview as the parent view.
2. Put some view as the subview of the scrollview.
3. Next create the `WKWebview` right after the content of the view, so that the `WKWebview`'s y would start right after the y axis of the view.

Here is the tricky part.

4. Calculate the WKWebview content height and update the frame to that of the content height.

You can do this by printing `webView.scrollView.contentSize.height` in this delegate method of the `WKWebview`--`didFinishNavigation`

5. Put other views below the new updated `WKWebview` y axis.

Hope this helps